# Why isn't Chrome seeing my css source map?

Tags: css, google-chrome, sass, source-maps

I just updated our gulp file to include the latest version of gulp-ruby-sass, so we could use the soucemaps feature included with the latest version of Sass.

I have confirmed that a source map is being outputted into the project's CSS folder, but chrome is not reading it.

"Enable CSS source maps" is checked in dev tools and I'm running the latest version of Chrome ( 37.0.2062.120) and I can see source maps in other projects.

Here is the generated sourcemap:

```
 {
  "version": 3,
  "mappings": ";;AAQA,IAAK,GACH,....bunch more JSON gobbley gook],
  "names": [],
  "file": "style.css"
 }
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: which version of sass are you using? I've recently had this same issue, source maps just aren't being read. My source map code is:

`{
"version": 3,
"mappings": "masses of mappings",
"sources": ["lots of file paths"],
"names": [],
"file": "styles.css"
}`

(I couldn't include all mappings and sources).

You seem to be missing the 'sources' section but I'm not. Did you solve the issue?

Comment: I'm using Grunt. It seems like the source map comment isn't being added to my compiled css file when sass is compiled via my watch task. If I just compile sass via my grunt task it is added and chrome reads the map. Might be another task messing with this, like autoprefixer. I'll investigate and comment if I find anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you are correct @Mark Weston - it was an issue with gulp-autoprefixer:
Turns out that gulp-autoprefixer was stripping out the `/*# sourceMappingURL=style.css.map */` comment at the bottom of my css file.

This is an open issue with gulp-autoprefixer: https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-autoprefixer/issues/1

Comment: the issue was closed on 2015-04-19

Answer (score 0):

Try these codes and **be careful with file paths**:

```
{
   "version": "3",
   "mappings":"AAKA,EAAG;EACC,SAAS,EANF,IAAI;EAOX,KAAK"
   "sources": ["content/style.css"],
   "file": "style.css"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

with gulp in sass i put the prefix first and it works

```
.pipe(sass({}))
```

.pipe(prefix('last 2 versions'))
.pipe(sourcemaps.write({includeContent: false}))